# Having trouble integrating AWS Mobile Hub with my Android project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-multidex, aws-mobilehub

so I am new to Android, and am trying to integrate my AWS Mobile Hub info with my application.

First, I download the SDK through the mobile hub, and then it asks me to add the following information to my app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

After the that, the next step says to add the following into dependencies into the app's app/build.gradle file, which I do:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies go here ...

    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.3')
}
```

This is where I believe everything goes wrong.  The instructions say: `Copy the contents of the java/com/amazonaws folder from the helper code you downloaded into the java/com folder of your Android Studio project.`

I drag the java/com/amazonaws folder (which I downloaded from AWS Mobile Hub) into my java/com folder (which, in my application looks like `java/com.example/MY_NAME/MY_PROJECT_NAME`)

Once I do this, I get a pop-up window saying "These files do not belong in the project"

I check a box that says "I want to edit these files anyways", there is also another option, but neither checks have made a difference in the final outcome.

After the amazonaws folder has been added to the java/com file, the instructions say to add the following to my custom class:

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient;
```

I receive the following errors/warnings: "cannot resolve symbol multidex", and "cannot resolve symbol amazonaws", and when I try to run the application, it does not build.

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong? This has been driving me absolutely crazy, and I have no idea where I am going wrong.  If you have experience with AWS mobile hub and Android, your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add the exact errors that you get during the build (by copy/pasting the errors from the log)?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 things happening.

1. Make sure you are making actual copies/moving the files from the starter code, and not dragging and creating links instead of actual copies.
2. Add the following to your gradle file above or below the sdk core compile statement

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Let me know if this helps. I've also taken note that we could improve the Mobile Hub integration instructions to make things smoother.

Thanks!